# Managing executors with fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, executor, onsaveinstancestate

I'm developing an app that performs tests on mobile network. The app has different Fragment (Home, Dashboard and Notification).

The Home fragment is able to start a periodic test using the Executors class.
There is an image "Off" displayed on the screen. If I click on it, the image becomes "On" and the tests start (`startTests.scheduleAtFixedRate(st,0,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`).

When I go to another screen another fragment is displayed, but the tests keep being executed.
When I come back to Home fragment, I get the "Off" image again, even if the tests keeps being executed. If I click on the image, it becomes "On" and another instance of Executors is created, so I have two tests being performed at the same time.
That's why changing Fragment makes the Home fragment being started as it was the first time it is displayed.

I could stop the executors when the fragment changes (overriding onSaveInstanceState), but I don't want to stop the tests, I'd like to keep the tests being performed and I'd like to have the image "On" being displayed when I come back to the Home fragment.

I could create a variable TEST_STARTED to be saved in onSaveInstanceState saying that the tests have been started, so when I come back to the Home fragment I know that the tests are going on. But how can I manage the Executor? I need to be able to stop the Executor when I click on the image.

```
package com.giorgio.roamingqosapp.ui.home

import ...

val TAG = ""
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private lateinit var interrOnImageView : ImageView
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private lateinit var interrOffImageView : ImageView
private var startTests = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
private lateinit var testProvider: ScheduledFuture<*>


class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
//    val sm = getContext()?.let { getSystemService(it,SmsManager::class.java) }

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        var text = ""

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        /*
        val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        */

        val tm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Activity.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        val SIMOperatorName = tm.simOperatorName
        val isRoaming = tm.isNetworkRoaming

        if (SIMOperatorName != null) {
            text = getString(R.string.registered_operator, SIMOperatorName)
            binding.registeredOperator.text = text
        }
        text = when (isRoaming) {
            true -> getString(R.string.roaming, "Roaming")
            false -> getString(R.string.roaming, "Home")
        }
        binding.roaming.text = text

        val ledImageView: ImageView = binding.registeredImageView
        ledImageView.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.led_verde))

        interrOffImageView = binding.testsOn
        interrOffImageView.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.off))
        interrOnImageView = binding.testsOff
        interrOnImageView.setImageDrawable(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.on))
        interrOnImageView.visibility = View.GONE
        interrOnImageView.setOnClickListener { startStopTest() }
        interrOffImageView.setOnClickListener { startStopTest() }

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    private fun startStopTest() {
        Log.i(TAG,"Check OnOff button image")

        if (interrOnImageView.visibility==View.VISIBLE) {
            interrOnImageView.visibility = View.GONE
            interrOffImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Log.i(TAG,"On -> Off")
            testProvider.cancel(true)
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.show, "Fermato il test periodico"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {
            interrOffImageView.visibility = View.GONE
            interrOnImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Log.i(TAG,"Off -> On")
            val st = ScheduledTests()
            testProvider = startTests.scheduleAtFixedRate(st,0,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.show, "Avviato il test periodico"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming that the Fragments share the same host Activity, you could use a Shared ViewModel approach & perform the test in MainActivity where the VM is & then use `by activityViewModels()` in your Fragment. You could also use a state in the VM to see if the test is executing or stopped.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try to learn how to use ViewModels